# rp2040_hal I2CPeripheralEventIterator usage

Tags: rust, rp2040, rust-embedded

Coming from C# and the .NET world, I needed to go bare metal with some IC (in this case the rp2040), and choose Rust based on every comment that I saw for the language.

Until now, I been able to easily use gpio, I2C as master, but my usage case, the rp2040 will be acting as a slave (or peripheral as the rp2040_hal calls it).

I'm able to see the device address when scanning the bus with Linux i2cdetect, but I am struggling with reading and writing to the device.

Sadly i wasn't able to see any useful example/usage case online, I'm wandering if someone had the "pleasure" to use this struct.

Keep in mind that I am bare metal #![no_std]

My main loop looks like this:

```
match i2c.next() {
            Some(I2CEvent::TransferRead) => {
                info!("transfer read");
                let write: [u8; 1] = [0x55];
                let byteswrite = i2c.write(&write);
                info!("{}", byteswrite);
            }
            Some(I2CEvent::TransferWrite) => {
                info!("transfer write");
                let mut result: [u8; 1] = [0; 1];
                let mut bytesread: usize;
                loop {
                    bytesread = i2c.read(&mut result);
                    if bytesread == 0 {
                        break;
                    }
                    info!("{:#04x}", &result);
                }
            }
            Some(I2CEvent::Start) => {}
            Some(I2CEvent::Stop) => {}
            Some(I2CEvent::Restart) => {
                info!("Restart");
            }
            None => {}
        }
```

I was expecting that using Linux i2cget and i2ctransfer, to be able to read and write to the device.